# Absurd "code markup" behavior...

Tags: support, markup, code

Can anyone explain how does this silly code markup behave? Help is insufficient, because I'm **absolutely unable to create a line break** in marked code block, whether in regular 4 spaces indent, whether in inline code markup - and it looks [nasty](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7966/aligning-text-vertically-in-tikz/7975#7975)!. Help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Formatting as code sample doesn't seem to work immediately after bulleted lists. I [edited](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7966/aligning-text-vertically-in-tikz/7975#7975) the respective post and created "faked" bulleted lists.

Comment: Ok, I already thought that I'm going crazy...Thanks!

Comment: @an_ant, @lockstep: It does work if you indent by 4 _additional_ spaces, as Ryan already mentioned in a comment. @an_ant: I edited your post accordingly.

Comment: @Hendrik Vogt: Now, that looks nice!

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see there is an issue. For example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{something}
\begin{document}
The next line is empty (not even four spaces)!

\end{document}
```

Comment: Follow the "nasty" link and see how it looked like before lockstep made his edit. That's what an_ant meant.

Comment: @Hendrik. The way the question was phrased, it looked like he meant in general. However, it seems that all is solved now in any case :-)

Comment: You are quite right. To understand the question, one _had to_ follow the link.